# MVC/Entity framework CORE searching through a linked model's data

Tags: entity-framework

Following the Contoso university tutorials, I've got a Person class which links to an Address class to give a one-to-many relationship

```
public class Person{
   public string FullName { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Address> AddressIDs { get; set; }
}

public class Address {
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PersonID")]
    [Display(Name = "Person ID")]
    public int? PersonID { get; set; }
    public virtual Person objPerson { get; set; }
}
```

So my view shows all of a person's addresses like this, which all works fine and for an individual person I get a list of all of their addresses.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.AddressIDs) {
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address1)
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address2)
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Postcode)
```

In the controller I use

```
var persons = from ps in _context.FullPerson
select ps;
persons = persons.Where(ps => ps.objPerson.Forename.Contains("Smith"));
```

to bring back all the "Smith"s from the database.   How can I extend this so I can search for only those records with a certain postcode?

```
persons = persons.Where(ps => ps.objPerson.Postcode.Contains("SW9"));.
```

This doesn't work because Postcode is in the connected Address model, not the Person model

```
persons = persons.Where(ps => ps.objPerson.AddressIDs.something.Contains("SW9"));
```

This doesn't work as the something are object references (I think) like Add, Aggregate<>, All<>, etc.

Am I supposed to use LINQ to join these two together (even though I think they're joined together already via EF) ?
Thanks

**Edit**
Using the answer below I got a list of the PersonIDs with the postcode I'm searching for

```
IQueryable<int> PersonIDsWithThisPostcode = _context.Addresses.Where(pst => pst.Postcode.Contains(p)).Select(b => b.PersonID);
```

Now I need to do a SQL IN command along these lines

```
persons = persons.Where(ps => ps.HumanID.Contains(PersonIDsWithThisPostcode));
```

this doesn't work because
*"int does not contain a definition for contains"*

Effectively, this is the SQL for the data I'm trying to retrieve

```
SELECT * FROM person
WHERE personid IN(
    SELECT personid FROM address
    WHERE postcode LIKE 'sw%'
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, even though everything is linked via models and entity framework, I've still got to write LINQ to get the two things linked.

```
IQueryable<int> PersonIDsWithThisPostcode = _context.Addresses.Where(pst => pst.Postcode.Contains(p)).Select(b => b.PersonID);
```

That gets all of the people with the postcode I'm searching for

```
persons = persons.Where(ps => PersonIDsWithThisPostcode.Contains(ps.PersonID));
```

That get's only the people in that list.

Thanks Gusti, you led me down the right path.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
var addresses= from adr in _context.Address
select adr;
addresses= addresses.Where(adr => adr.PostCode.Contains("zipCode") && 
adr.objPerson.Forename.Contains("Smith"));
```